# Java class Process: can't execute third party program via .sh

Tags: java, linux, process, sh, tesseract

I need to run a .sh script, I already figured out how to do it, but I have another problem. it cannot see third-party (installed) commands, as in this case it cannot find the tesseract command, although when launched through the Linux terminal, it successfully finds this command
For example, java can recognize the echo command, but it does not see the tesseract command

void for running script:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "./myscript.sh");
builder.inheritIO();
        Process process = builder.start();
    }
}
```

sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello this is message from script"
echo "using tesseract"
tesseract test.png out1 -l rus+eng
```

Error on startup:

```
./myscript.sh: line 5: tesseract: command not found
```

When running the script through the Linux terminal, there are no problems, the command successfully performs its function. If you need the output from the terminal, then here:

```
hello this is message from script
using tesseract
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.
```

I tried to execute the command from the link as shown below:

```
/bin/tesseract test.png out1 -l rus+eng
```

function still didn't work

Comment: What does "*do not work*" mean? Do you get a compilation error? If so: please [edit] the post, add the compiler error and highlight the line of code causing the compilation error. Does it throw an exception? If so: please [edit] the post, add the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. Do you observe unexpected behaviour? If so: please [edit] the post, add a [MRE], as we as expected and observed output.

Comment: "an error" is a very unclear description... would be helpful at least to know which error (message) (I would also at least use `builder.inheritIO()` to see the output of given command)

Comment: Did you try changing `tesseract test.png out1 -l rus+eng` to `tesseract test.png out1 -l rus+eng`?

Comment: you wrote the same thing, check the message for typos  @dan1stisonstrike

Comment: My fault, I meant `/bin/tesseract test.png out1 -l rus+eng to tesseract test.png out1 -l rus+eng` - I forgot to actually change it.

Comment: I already tried that and it still couldn't find the command, which is weird because the path is correct. @dan1stisonstrike

Same error: ./myscript.sh: line 5: /bin/tesseract: No such file or directory

Comment: An odd path. Usually `/usr/bin/tesseract`

Comment: What's the output of `whereis tesseract` (outside of the script/Java application/where it works)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @dan1stisonstrike Thanks for trying to help, I've edited the original question.

Comment: When running `whereis tesseract` in your terminal, what output do you get?

Comment: Output: `hello this is message from script
using tesseract
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.1.1 with Leptonica
Warning: Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead.`

path: /bin/tesseract @dan1stisonstrike

Comment: Use the full path to tesseract in the script. In point of fact, you don't need a script. You could run tesseract directly

Comment: I already used the full path, the result is the same... @g00se

Comment: @dan1stisonstrike asked a question to which I don't see the answer

Comment: I answered all his questions @g00se

Comment: What you showed doesn't seem like the output of the command `whereis tesseract`. The `whereis` is an important part of the command.

Comment: output: `hello this is message from script
using tesseract
tesseract:
text-file.png:
out1:
bin: /usr/bin
bin: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
bin: /usr/lib
bin: /usr/lib64
bin: /etc
bin: /usr/etc
bin: /usr/include
bin: /usr/libexec
bin: /usr/share
bin: /app/bin
rus+eng:`

Comment: You keep posting output from your *script*. That's *not* what we're asking for. Read the request carefully

Comment: `tesseract: /usr/bin/tesseract /usr/share/man/man1/tesseract.1.gz` its output @g00se

Comment: So, as you can see, the path is *not* `/bin/tesseract` but rather what I said it should be, namely  `/usr/bin/tesseract`

Comment: I also tried your version that time, but it didn't help either @g00se

Comment: Try `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/tesseract","test.png","out1","-l","rus+eng").inheritIO(); builder.start()`

Comment: @g00se It didn't help, I actually did it myself.

Comment: It works for me. Please post what you did

Comment: I copied your code and pasted it into the Main class in the Main method, in the root folder of the project there is a test.png file that needs to be processed with the tesseract command, I can do this using the Linux terminal and there are no problems, but when I try to do the same through the Java code, it cannot find this command, and it successfully finds other commands like ECHO @g00se

Comment: That's a wholly different problem and it is caused by the current directory not being what you think it is. You can find out what it really is by printing the system property `user.dir`. That's where the image needs to go

Comment: @g00se so the problem is not in the image, she cannot find exactly the tesseract command itself

Comment: OK, I thought you were referring to the image file. There *can't* be a problem finding Tesseract itself using the code I gave you because the full path to it is given

Comment: I really don't know why she writes that there is no such command, even when I enter the full path, I don't know what the problem is @g00se

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/tesseract`

Comment: @g00se -`rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35128 feb  9  2022 /usr/bin/tesseract`

Comment: Then no reason why it shouldn't work. Use the absolute path to the image file with my code for the time being

Comment: It didn't help either. I tried to copy the tesseract file and move it to the root folder of the project and java started to see this command, but got errors that there were no dependencies @g00se

Comment: Ordinarily that would solve nothing but might very likely cause even more problems. There's something weird going on with your environment but unfortunately that's difficult to diagnose from sketchy descriptions

Comment: I also reinstalled Linux several times (not for this reason) and it still didn't work. I also tried calling /usr/bin/echo and there are no errors in the file search, I don't know what

Comment: Probably a support case at this point

Comment: @g00se I tried building the project into a jar and running it, and you know what? everything works for me, I don't know what it is connected with

Comment: Glad you got it working finally

Comment: @g00se Thanks for trying to help all this time! I'm also very happy with how it turned out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have the folder containing `tesseract` program in the `PATH` variable or else it won't work.

## What is the `PATH`?

Setting the `PATH` (Linux, `:`-separated) or the `Path` (Windows, `;`-separated) environment variable sets the list of directories the system searches when you invoke a program name without a directory preceding it.

For instance if I go to the command line and type `java` the system will loop over each directory in my `PATH` to see if `java` exists there and is executable. Once it finds one it executes it and exits the loop.

If, however I run `/opt/java/bin/java` no path lookup is performed.

Usually your shell either sets (or inherits) the `PATH` variable upon login, but you can do it from the shell too:

```bash
export PATH='/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/java/bin/java'
```

Every program invoked after this `export` statement will have their `PATH` overwritten by the value from your shell.

You can set the `PATH` (or any environment variable) for a single program by prefixing it with the variable set on the same line:

```bash
PATH='/bin:/usr/bin:/home/myuser/bin' myprogram -arg1 -arg2
```

PATH entries without a leading `/` are interpreted to be relative to the current working directory (`.`):

```bash
PATH='bin:/usr/bin:/bin'
```

**Caveat:** It's not recommended to omit `/bin` and `/usr/bin` from the PATH. I'd try only ever *adding* to the path variable:

```bash
export PATH="$PATH:/home/myuser/add:/home/myuser/bin"
```

## Without using the `PATH`

If you don't want to update it in the `PATH` variable, you can refer to it by full or relative path name in the script.

For the following examples, I'm going to assume the following file layout:

- `src/.../.../.../Main.java` (compiled somehow)
- `myscript.sh`
- `bin/teserract`

This should work:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# WORKDIR = The current dir (relative to how the script is invoked) where myscript.sh resides
WORKDIR=$(dirname "$0")

"$WORKDIR/bin/tesseract" test.png out1 -l rus+eng
```

Consider also that on many systems `sh myscript.sh` is not the same thing as `bash myscript.sh` or `./myscript.sh`. `/bin/sh` traditionally refers to POSIX shell, which has fewer features than Bash. It may trip you up if you decide to use some advanced Bash features. For this reason, I'd suggest changing the Java to either `new ProcessBuilder("./myscript.sh")` or `new ProcessBuilder("bash", "./myscript.sh")`.

Comment: *If you don't want to update it in the PATH variable* What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: @g00se I updated my answer to give an explanation

Comment: OK. This whole question is shrouded in mystery, not the least of which is that `tesseract` was probably in the path all along, at the location I said it should be at